# Getting error in Parquet Input steps in Pentaho Data Integration

Tags: parquet, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration, fastparquet, parquet-dataset

2024/01/18 15:33:36 - Test_Parquet_Input_Step -  Transformation has allocated a new step: [Dummy (do nothing)].0
2024/01/18 15:33:36 - Test_Parquet_Input_Step - This transformation can be replayed with replay date: 2024/01/18 15:33:36
2024/01/18 15:33:36 - Test_Parquet_Input_Step - Initialising 2 steps...
2024/01/18 15:33:36 - Parquet input.0 - Released server socket on port 0
2024/01/18 15:33:36 - Dummy (do nothing).0 - Released server socket on port 0
2024/01/18 15:33:36 - Test_Parquet_Input_Step - Step [Parquet input.0] initialized flawlessly.
2024/01/18 15:33:36 - Test_Parquet_Input_Step - Step [Dummy (do nothing).0] initialized flawlessly.
2024/01/18 15:33:36 - Test_Parquet_Input_Step - Transformation has allocated 2 threads and 1 rowsets.
2024/01/18 15:33:36 - Parquet input.0 - Starting to run...
2024/01/18 15:33:36 - Dummy (do nothing).0 - Starting to run...
2024/01/18 15:33:36 - Parquet input.0 - ERROR (version 9.1.0.0-324, build 9.1.0.0-324 from 2020-09-07 05.09.05 by buildguy) : Unexpected error
2024/01/18 15:33:36 - Parquet input.0 - ERROR (version 9.1.0.0-324, build 9.1.0.0-324 from 2020-09-07 05.09.05 by buildguy) : java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$POSIX.stat(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/io/nativeio/NativeIO$POSIX$Stat;
2024/01/18 15:33:36 - Parquet input.0 -     at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$POSIX.stat(Native Method)
2024/01/18 15:33:36 - Parquet input.0 -     at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$POSIX.getStat(NativeIO.java:455)
2024/01/18 15:33:36 - Parquet input.0 -     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus.loadPermissionInfoByNativeIO(RawLocalFileSystem.java:796)
2024/01/18 15:33:36 - Parquet input.0 -     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus.loadPermissionInfo(RawLocalFileSystem.java:710)
2024/01/18 15:33:36 - Parquet input.0 -     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus.getPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:678)
2024/01/18 15:33:36 - Parquet input.0 -     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocatedFileStatus.(LocatedFileStatus.java:52)
2024/01/18 15:33:36 - Parquet input.0 -     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$4.next(FileSystem.java:2142)
2024/01/18 15:33:36 - Parquet input.0 -     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$4.next(FileSystem.java:2122)
2024/01/18 15:33:36 - Parquet input.0 -     at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:314)
2024/01/18 15:33:36 - Parquet input.0 -     at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:274)
2024/01/18 15:33:36 - Parquet input.0 -     at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetInputFormat.listStatus(ParquetInputFormat.java:373)
2024/01/18 15:33:36 - Parquet input.0 -     at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetInputFormat.getFooters(ParquetInputFormat.java:411)
2024/01/18 15:33:36 - Parquet input.0 -     at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetInputFormat.getSplits(ParquetInputFormat.java:336)
2024/01/18 15:33:36 - Parquet input.0 -     at org.pentaho.hadoop.shim.common.format.parquet.delegate.apache.PentahoApacheInputFormat.lambda$getSplits$6(PentahoApacheInputFormat.java:174)
2024/01/18 15:33:36 - Parquet input.0 -     at org.pentaho.hadoop.shim.common.format.HadoopFormatBase.inClassloader(HadoopFormatBase.java:36)
2024/01/18 15:33:36 - Parquet input.0 -     at org.pentaho.hadoop.shim.common.format.parquet.delegate.apache.PentahoApacheInputFormat.getSplits(PentahoApacheInputFormat.java:173)
2024/01/18 15:33:36 - Parquet input.0 -     at org.pentaho.big.data.kettle.plugins.formats.impl.parquet.input.ParquetInput.initSplits(ParquetInput.java:172)
2024/01/18 15:33:36 - Parquet input.0 -     at org.pentaho.big.data.kettle.plugins.formats.impl.parquet.input.ParquetInput.processRow(ParquetInput.java:86)
2024/01/18 15:33:36 - Parquet input.0 -     at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:62)
2024/01/18 15:33:36 - Parquet input.0 -     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
2024/01/18 15:33:36 - Parquet input.0 - child index = 0, logging object : org.pentaho.di.core.logging.LoggingObject@1dc83609 parent=144a18fe-b007-4c83-ba79-ec113470258e
2024/01/18 15:33:36 - Parquet input.0 - Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=0, W=0, U=0, E=1)
2024/01/18 15:33:36 - Test_Parquet_Input_Step - Transformation detected one or more steps with errors.
2024/01/18 15:33:36 - Test_Parquet_Input_Step - Transformation is killing the other steps!
2024/01/18 15:33:36 - Test_Parquet_Input_Step - Looking at step: Parquet input
2024/01/18 15:33:36 - Dummy (do nothing).0 - Signaling 'output done' to 0 output rowsets.
2024/01/18 15:33:36 - Dummy (do nothing).0 - Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=0, W=0, U=0, E=0)
2024/01/18 15:33:36 - Test_Parquet_Input_Step - Looking at step: Dummy (do nothing)
2024/01/18 15:33:36 - Test_Parquet_Input_Step - searching for annotations
2024/01/18 15:33:36 - Test_Parquet_Input_Step - no annotations found
2024/01/18 15:33:36 - Test_Parquet_Input_Step - ERROR (version 9.1.0.0-324, build 9.1.0.0-324 from 2020-09-07 05.09.05 by buildguy) : Errors detected!
2024/01/18 15:33:36 - Spoon - The transformation has finished!!
2024/01/18 15:33:36 - Test_Parquet_Input_Step - ERROR (version 9.1.0.0-324, build 9.1.0.0-324 from 2020-09-07 05.09.05 by buildguy) : Errors detected!
2024/01/18 15:33:36 - Test_Parquet_Input_Step - ERROR (version 9.1.0.0-324, build 9.1.0.0-324 from 2020-09-07 05.09.05 by buildguy) : Errors detected!

**I am trying to read a sample parquet file and convert that to csv file.
for this i have used the Parquet Input step to read the file, but while executing I am getting the error.**

2024/01/18 15:11:16 - Parquet input.0 - ERROR (version 9.1.0.0-324, build 9.1.0.0-324 from 2020-09-07 05.09.05 by buildguy) : Unexpected error
2024/01/18 15:11:16 - Parquet input.0 - ERROR (version 9.1.0.0-324, build 9.1.0.0-324 from 2020-09-07 05.09.05 by buildguy) : java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$POSIX.stat(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/io/nativeio/NativeIO$POSIX$Stat;

Comment: This one seems to have nothing to do with `fastparquet` - is it java? In any case, I'm sure others would like far more information about what you are doing, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask